# Prime ideals of the complete ring of quotients

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization

For a commutative unitary ring $R$, let $Q(R)$ be the complete
ring of quotients of $R$, please see
(http://planetmath.org/completeringofquotients) for more
information. In general,  the  complete ring of quotients  may be
larger than the "classical ring of quotients", that is,
$R\subseteq T(R)\subseteq Q(R)$, where $T(R)=S^{-1}R$ is classical
ring of quotients of $R$ with $S$ is the set of all non-zero
divisors of $R $. There is a well-known characterization for the set of
all prime ideals of $T(R)$. Is there a similar description for
the set of all prime ideals of $Q(R)$?